Math Command Different Font
for a homework template, I want to use Arial as the main font, for the header, footer, and just normal text. For math mode, I want to use the default font, for commands with "\" I want to use the default font again.
My document looks like this:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.78in]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

\(500A\)\\
\(500\si{\ampere}\)

\end{document} 

When I write \si{\ampere} it writes it with Arial which I don't want. I want the header, footer, title page, and normal texts to be Arial.
And additional to my question currently when I write things it overflows to my footer how can I prevent this?
Note: Due to original Arial font I am compiling with XeLaTex, if you have another solution I am open for them.

Please provide code people can compile. Ideally, substitute a standard font from your TeX install for Arial. (Obviously, substitute a unicode font and not a traditional one.) There is no \ampere in your example, even though that's central to your question. How is \ampere defined? It is not a standard LaTeX command.

@cfr I just edited the question with my whole document, you should be able to compile it with XeLaTex right now. And ampere was just an example, I wrote it since it writes a letter.

Please reduce your code to a minimal example. It should demonstrate the problem without anything extra. Independently of that, go through your preamble in your real document and remove (1) duplicate packages (2) conflicting packages and (3) packages you aren't using. You definitely should remove t1enc. Not only is it obsolete for the T1 encoding. The T1 encoding is anyway incompatible with TU, which is what fontspec uses.

Per my understanding, for math font, you want  to use CMR family, please correct me if I am wrong

@cfr Hi there again, I edited the code. Currently since I set the main font as Arial (\si{\ampere}) is also Arial, but I don't want that. Normally, it is cmr but non italic.

Tell fontspec not to change the \mathrm font from the default:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.78in]{geometry}

\usepackage[mode=math]{siunitx}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\(500\mathrm{A}\)\\
\(500\si{\ampere}\)

\end{document}

Alternatively, set your math and \mathrm fonts to Computer Modern:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.78in]{geometry}

\usepackage[mode=math]{siunitx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathrm{NewCM10-Regular}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\(500\mathrm{A}\)\\
\(500\si{\ampere}\)

\end{document}



siunitx format units with \mathrm witch matches the text font. This is because units are text, not math expressions.
If you want to change this, I suggest to load the package unicode-math which provides the command \symup to get upright math font. Then, change the command used by siunitx:
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\sisetup{unit-font-command=\symup}

Full example (I use the Liberation Sans font because I don't have Arial installed):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.78in]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage{unicode-math}
\sisetup{unit-font-command=\symup}

\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}

\begin{document}

\[ 500~A \]
\[ 500~\mathrm{A} \]
\[ \qty{500}{\ampere} \]

\end{document}


Alternatively, if you want that all \mathrm commands display upright math font, use:
\unimathsetup{mathrm=sym}

Complete example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.78in]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{mathrm=sym}

\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}

\begin{document}

\[ 500~A \]
\[ 500~\mathrm{A} \]
\[ \qty{500}{\ampere} \]

\end{document}


